# How to make a virtual USB drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive

How can I make a virtual USB drive in Windows? Can it be done with DAEMON Tools or something like that?

The reason is that I need the USB drive to use them instead of a physical USB. Sometimes I need to load certificate from USB but I left it at home and when I'm on the job I want to make a virtual USB and put on them certificate, so how can I do that?

Comment: It's maybe sound like xy problem but it's very clear and exact question, anyway ... i need usb drive to use them instead of physical usb. Sometimes i need to load certificate from usb but i left it at home and when i'm on job i want to make virtual usb and put on them certificate, so how can i do that? ... thnx for effort

Comment: You could use a Ramdisk: http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk

Comment: @AxelKemper thnx man for help it helps me, but still i didn't find way to fool application which check it certificates are on real usb or not ...

Comment: Yes, the idea of smartcards and USB tokens is that nobody should be able to copy them (https://www.entrust.com/smartcards-and-usb-tokens/). To use a "two-factor authentification" you have to 1) know something (a PIN or password) and 2) have something (the token). You could use an X.509 PKI certificate stored in a file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

Comment: Many programs require a removable usb to interact with rather than an HDD folder and thus providing a method to build a virtual removable usb is an important query in its own right.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [ImDisk](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/imdisk_toolkit_64_bit.html) to create a removable USB drive

```
imdisk -a -s 536870912 -m R: -o rem -p "/fs:ntfs /q /y"
```

```
-a      Attach a virtual disk. This will configure and attach a virtual disk
        with the parameters specified and attach it to the system.
-s      Size of the virtual disk. Size is number of bytes ...
-m      Specifies a drive letter or mount point for the new virtual disk ...
-o rem  Specifies that the device should be created with removable media
        characteristics.  ...
-p ...  The 'format' command to create a filesystem when the new virtual disk has 
        been created. "/fs:ntfs /q /y" is: Create an NTFS filesystem with quick 
        formatting and without user interaction.
```

#### How to install

- For a CMD version download [ImDisk Toolkit](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/imdisk_toolkit_64_bit.html),
  extract it with 7-Zip and copy these 2 files:

  ```
    ..\cpl\i386\imdisk.cpl
    ..\cli\i386\imdisk.exe
  ```
- For a GUI version download [ImDisk Toolkit](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/imdisk_toolkit_64_bit.html) and just install it.

#### Further links

- Full command line syntax : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RZMh3QPQ
  Alternatively: ["ImDisk help" at GitHub](https://gist.github.com/stokito/19e377c872dd85ee4445eabce97fa2e8).
- Support forum: http://reboot.pro/forum/59-imdisk/

Comment: Please don't write USB in your answer, ImDisk creates just removable drive not USB removable drive. If vmware is running that will not detect a new usb drive and will not provide an option to attache to guest.