# Mapping Removable media via Windows Remote Desktop as Removable Media

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, removable-media

I have a Windows Server to which I'm connecting via Remote Desktop Connection. On my local Desktop I have a CF card as removable media connected. I want to have access to this as a Removable Media also on the Server. The reason is that I have a software on the Server that only can write exports to removable media.

When I connect to the server I can in the RDC use the option to bring local resources through the connection. But then I see it as a network drive on my server and not as a removable media (and therefore my software ignores it).

Is there anyway that I can change the network drive to be seen as a removable media?
Is there a way to map the local removable media to the server as a removable media? 
Is there any known software that can emulate a removable media?

I only need my software to export the files to the removable media. After that I can copy them to anywhere and write them to the CF-card where I can access the card physically.

The server is a VM why it's not that easy to have a physical removable media on the machine since it can change physical platforms over time without my knowledge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can convert a network share into a removable drive,
but you can create a fake removable drive to which the program may write.
Then you can copy the files to your network share using RDP.

The tool to use is
[ImDisk Toolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/).

I quote from another [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/625443/8672):

> You can use ImDisk to create a removable USB drive
>
> ```
> imdisk -a -s 536870912 -m R: -o rem -p "fs:ntfs /q /y"
> ```
>
> ```
> -a      Attach a virtual disk. This will configure and attach a virtual disk
>         with the parameters specified and attach it to the system.
> -s      Size of the virtual disk. Size is number of bytes
> -m      Specifies a drive letter or mount point for the new virtual disk
> -o rem  Specifies that the device should be created with removable media
>         characteristics.
> -p      'format' command to create a filesystem when the new virtual disk has 
>         been created. "/fs:ntfs /q /y" is: Create an NTFS filesystem with quick 
>         formatting and without user interaction.
> ```