# Is it possible to load a VHDX virtual drive so it's seen as a removeable drive by windows?

Tags: vhd, virtual-drive, vhdx

I'm wanting to synchronise a "virtual USB drive" between computers.

Reason is, the software I use for lighting, GrandMA2 onpc, is based around the concept of a lighting console with an internal hard disk and the ability to export show data to a USB drive for migrating between machines. I know this is super niche, but if windows doesn't see a drive as "removable" GMA2 won't see it as an option to save data to.

I've made a VHDX virtual drive in disk management, it's fat32 (as required by gma2)
I've mounted it successfully.

But it appears as an internal drive to windows.

Anyone know of perhaps a registry string I could add or change to change how it's perceived by the OS?

Comment: Potential solution: https://superuser.com/questions/609899/how-to-make-a-virtual-usb-drive-in-windows

Comment: Windows 8+ can mount VHDK files.  However, Windows will indeed treat it as a disk, that is installed. Is there a reason this is a problem? USB removable flash drives appear in Disk Management.

Comment: The software I'm using will either save files to a folder inside "programdata" on the c:\ or it'll save to a detected USB stick. I'm wanting to create a virtual USB stick to save to for backing up and synchronisation of data between different machines. I currently have it synching the program data location but I feel like this is a bad plan. The way it saves to a USB drive is designed for migrating show data between computers and lighting consoles - but synchronising the "internal drive data" could cause conflicts when other settings are saved on one device.

Comment: I've found out Daemon tools can do it!